# Безопасно ли использовать Firebase в React Native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, безопасность, react-native

Безопасно ли использовать Firebase в RN?
В приложении должен лежать конфиг с данными для использования Firebase

формата

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'api-key',
  authDomain: 'project-id.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://project-id.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'project-id',
  storageBucket: 'project-id.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'sender-id',
  appId: 'app-id',
  measurementId: 'G-measurement-id',
};
```

Разве не получится разобрать .apk файл и получить эти данные и потом с помощью них посмотреть хранилище Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

Не получится.
Для чтения или записи в БД - есть "правила безопасности"
И вам стоит настроить их, "конфиг" никакого "вреда" не сделает